# Strange thing about sizeof

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain, why size of the `objC` is 8, not 12?

I think, that if it in the class `C` I have object with type `int` and in `A`, `B` - `char`, then after creation of the `objC` it should be 4 bytes for `objA`, `objB` and `ObjC`.

```
class A {
    char a;
};

class B : A {
    char b;
};

class C : B {
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    A objA;
    B objB;
    C objC;

    cout << sizeof(objA) << endl; // 1
    cout << sizeof(objB) << endl; // 2
    cout << sizeof(objC) << endl; // 8! Why not 12?

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

In this case `sizeof(objC)` will be 12:

```
class A {
    char a;
};

class B : A {
    int b; // Here is int
};

class C : B {
    char c; // Here is char
};
```

Comment: Read wikipage on [data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Comment: Why do you expect it to be 12?  I would expect it to be 8 if `sizeof(objB)` is 2

Comment: The answer is always alignment.

Comment: Why is it so many don't trust the value that `sizeof` returns to them?  That should be the real question.  It is what it is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that `class C` will have:

- 2x 1-byte chars
- 2-bytes of padding, so the int starts on a 4-byte boundary.
- 1x 4-byte integer
- Making a total of 8-bytes

To keep the integer aligned on a boundary, there'll be 2-bytes of padding, making ***8 bytes***.

How do you get 12??

---

In your second example, `class C` will have:

- a 1-byte char.
- 3-bytes of padding before the int. (keep the int on a 4-byte boundary)
- a 4-byte int.
- a 1-byte char.
- Making a total of 9-bytes.

Sizes are rounded up to the nearest 4-bytes, which is 12.

Comment: The OP probably got 12 by assuming that classes A and B would both be aligned to a 4-byte boundary before being considered part of the subclasses that inherit them. So 4+4+4 = 12.

Comment: "Sizes are rounded up to the nearest 4-bytes" - not true in general, e.g `sizeof(objA)` in OPs code is `1`.  ITYM that the struct size is usually rounded up to a multiple of the alignment of its most-aligney member, so that an array of such structs works.

Comment: @M.M "Most-aligney member", I'm going to have to keep that term in mind!

Comment: @Barry hmm..please don't :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, there is one padding. In the second case there are two paddings.

The first case will be:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b |   |   |     c         |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
<-     4      ->|<-    4      ->|
```

The second case will be:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a |   |   |   |     b         | c |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
<-     4      ->|<-    4      ->|<-    4      ->|
```